# How to open a File object(HTML) and parse it in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'd like to open(load) a File object that I got by DriveApp.getFilesByName method.

Then, after that, I'd like to parse the file with XmlService.parse method.

But, the problem is that I can't find a method to open(load) a File object.

Here is the least code.

What am I supposed to write after I got a File object which is a html format file?

```
function test() {


  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("test.htm").next();

  // What am I supposed to write here?
  // I can't find a method to open up a File Object in API list.

  var doc = XmlService.parse(html);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method call `getFilesByName().next()` only returns a File -- an internal Google Drive type. What you need is a string for the XmlService to parse. You can do this through the Google Apps Script `Blob` type. Do something like this

```
var html = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
var doc = XmlService.parse(html);`
```

That will give the XmlService type a string that it can actually parse.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to try it now!